# Checkbox toggle menu

Tags: jquery, html

Excuse the vague question, I'm really not sure how to describe what I'm looking for well enough, so I made this ultra-professional "picture story" with paint.

**Image 1**: Those funny "boxes" resemble html checkboxes. Let's say they have the class: *checkbox-menu*

[image: Image1]

**Image 2**: When checked...

[image: Image2]

**Image 3**: ...a popover appears with stuff in it that's irrelevant to this post.

[image: Image3]

**Image 4**: When checking a additional checkbox on the site...

[image: Image4]

**Image 5**: ...**the pop-over slides down**...

[image: Image5]

**Image 6**: ...to the latest checked box.

[image: Image6]

Additional behavior is that it hides when clicked outside or unchecking a already checked box.

I have really no clue how to get there, I hope someone can point me into the right direction, thanks in advance!

Comment: Love the drawing. I believe what you're looking for is "tool tips"

Comment: If you code as good as you draw, I don't want to see the site. LOL But yes, I agree to @Rich. You're after a tool tip kind of solution.

Comment: This may be some work (maybe 3 to 4 hours) and nobody is going to code it for you. Go hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: I don't want anyone to code it for me - although that would be nice since it's for a open source forum theme. :P I'm just not sure how to go about the sliding down part - getting the position right. If someone could point me somewhere, that would be great enough. Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever read about jQuery?

Comment: Yes HerrSerker, this is a jQuery related question, hence why it's in the tags. I know the jQuery *basics* but I don't know how I would achive this.

Comment: You could simply place a div next to each checkbox, make then invisible, and show using some animation, as per click. That's all.

Comment: Yeah I thought about that, but I really want the sliding down part...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working demo to get you started, though there are many more customizations you can play around with.

## [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/W39mX/)

I'm basing the toggle menu on Boostrap's [Popover](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers), but really, you want to create a single div that is initially hidden, and you will later control in terms of location and visibility.  That way you get a seamless transition between different checkboxes.

Declare the popover anywhere on your page and then set the `display` to `hidden`

```html
<div id='CheckBoxPopover' class="popover fade right in" style="display: hidden;">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    <h3 class="popover-title">Some Info</h3>
    <div class="popover-content"></div>
</div>
```

To create nice transitions when it moves, you can use **CSS** *Transition* property like this:

```css
#CheckBoxPopover {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
       -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
        -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
         -o-transition: all 1s ease;
            transition: all 1s ease;    
}
```

Here's some HTML for the rest of the page:

```html
<div class="checkBoxTips">
    <input type="checkbox"></input>
    <input type="checkbox"></input>
</div>
```

Finally, in **JavaScript** you can control what happens when someone clicks on an input element inside of your `checkBoxTips` class.  Using jQuery's [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/), you can get the position of the element that's been clicked.  Then you can [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) or [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the visibility based on the context.

```js
// create a single access point for your popover
var $pop = $("#CheckBoxPopover");

$('.checkBoxTips input').click(function () {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $pop.css('left',offset.left + 20);
    $pop.css('top',offset.top - 25);
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $pop.show();
    } else {
        $pop.hide();
    }
});
```

## Customizations:

If the item is unchecked, you could simply hide the popover, but you might want to search for the first checked input element in the div.  If there are any results, then move the popover to that location.  If not, *THEN* you can hide it.  Something like this:

```js
var $checkedBoxes = $('.checkBoxTips input:checked')
if ($checkedBoxes.length >0) {
    setPopover($checkedBoxes[0]);
} else {
    $pop.hide();
}
```

When you're moving the popover, you also have full control through jQuery over any of the div contents, so you should change the header or make any other modifications you want. As an example, you can take the title attribute of the current element and set it as the popover text:

```js
var title = $(element).attr("title");
$pop.find("h3.popover-title").text(title);
```

If you want the popover to hide anytime something other than the checkbox is clicked, you can attach a click event handler to the entire document which will hide the popup.

```js
$(document).click(function () {
    $pop.hide();
});
```

In order for this to not close the popup on every click, you will have to tell the input click function to `stopPropagation` of the event from bubbling up to other containing elements like this:

```js
$('.checkBoxTips input').click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should look into jquery UI [Tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#default) you can customize most of it

Comment: The API looks great indeed for this. I'm still not sure how to go about the animation and the related construct though, here's a little video of what I want - that's probably more helpful than the funny images and also pretty exact... http://www.screenr.com/3AuH What I'm looking for is basicily the trick that allows to move a element correct from one element to the other, you see this effect in a lot of navigations.